# Imposing constraints on method arguments, besides their number and their types, in Java

Tags: java, methods, arguments

I am trying to define a method (called "range") which returns an array. I pass two integers, say m and n, and it returns an array of length (n-m) as it is described in the following listing: Implicitly I suppose n is greater than m. But I would like to impose this condition explicitly. 
Is there any way to impose this kind of conditions on arguments of methods?

You may suggest I change the method so that I pass m and (n-m) instead of m and n into the method, but it still assumes that n-m is a positive integer. So we need to find a way to impose these types of constrains on method arguments.

```
public static int[] range(int m, int n) {
    int[] r=new int[n-m];
    for(int i=0; i<n-m; i++)
        r[i]=m+i;

    return r;
}
```

Comment: `Math.abs(n-m)` in this case. More generally, you'll probably want to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: `Preconditions.checkArgument(n > m);`?

Comment: If you just want to create the array of size equal to the difference, why don't you take the absolute value of (n-m) instead?

Comment: I'd like to get a warning if I pass an invalid set of arguments into method, like when I am supposed to pass an integer into a method but I instead pass a double.

Comment: If you are asking "how do I do this at compile time?", then the answer is "you can't" - you can't enforce constraints on data only known at runtime at compile time.

Comment: You could throw an Error or Exception : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm
Or create your own handling system that outputs some usage text `if(n < m)`

Comment: @ Oliver Charlesworth: Could you please elaborate a little more about class Preconditions? What else is possible to do using this class? It sounds interesting.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh - It's nothing magic, it's just a [library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) for wrapping up a common pattern - throwing an exception if certain conditions aren't met.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth: I learned a lot from you comments. Thank you!

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-)

Comment: And I thank everybody for their quick and very useful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to express this using the *type system* (at least not the *java* type system).

You can do things like:

- having code that checks such conditions - to throw an IllegalArgumentException
- use `asserts` in a similar way (but that requires the JVM to be started with certain parameters)

Meaning: you can have *runtime* checks; but for "compile" resp. "programming" time - you can only give *informal* advice (such as detailed javadoc about the contract of the method).

Comment: Using javadoc and throwing an IllegalArgumentException sounds good enough. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh For the record: when going for unchecked exceptions to be thrown - still document them via javadoc!

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to statically (at compile-time) ensure a post-condition that depends on information that is only available at run-time. This concept is called [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). In general, dependent type checking is undecidable. Thus, if you have a language that supports dependent type checking, it is possible to write a program where the type checker cannot tell whether it is type correct. An example for such a language is [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/), which is similar to Haskell. Idris is a language that should only be used for research to get a feeling about how dependent types can actually be used in programming (dependent types are a well known concept from automatic theorem provers).

As far as I am aware, there is no such thing like dependent type checking for Java, thus you can only check pre- and post-conditions dynamically (at run-time), e.g. by throwing an exception if an unexpected case occurred.

Comment: I listened to a podcast about type driven development last week; and was inclined to mention Idris. Good that I didnt do that and leave some space for your answer ;-) ... have my vote for that ;-)

Comment: Very useful information. I see the problem from a higher level now. Thanks for your answer.